# How to find length of a 2D byte array and to how use that 2D byte array in ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: audio, javasound, java, javax.sound.sampled

Firstly, in the following code what I am trying to do is find the length of a 2D byte array by using 'byteBuffer[0].length', but it is actually not working. When I am printing 'byteBuffer[0].length' it is giving the output as 4 instead of 882000, which (latter) should be the correct output according to the parameters I had passed. So how do I iterate it in my loop?

Secondly, I want to pass 'byteBuffer' in 'ByteArrayInputStream', but in 'ByteArrayInputStream' we cannot pass a 2D array. So is there a way of appending the values and use it there? And I also need to pass the values of 'Frequency1' and 'Frequency2' alternatively and save them in .wav format, so that I can play them accordingly in my media player. For example: an Ambulance's siren.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class AudioPlay {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    final double SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;             // Audio sampling rate
    int time = in.nextInt();                        //Time specified by user in seconds
    int frequency1 = in.nextInt();                  //Frequency specified by the user in hz
    int frequency2 = in.nextInt();

    //Size of buffer, in case time is 10 seconds it will be [2][441000]
    float buffer[][] = new float[2][(int) (time * SAMPLING_RATE)];   

    for (int sample = 0; sample < buffer[0].length; sample++) {
        double cycle = sample / SAMPLING_RATE;                  //Fraction of cycle between samples
        buffer[0][sample] = (float) (Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency1 * cycle));   //Storing value at every index of 1st row
        buffer[1][sample] = (float) (Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency2 * cycle));   //Storing value at every index of 2nd row
    }

    //Size of byteBuffer, in case time is 10sec it will be [2][882000]
    byte byteBuffer[][] = new byte[2][(int)(buffer.length * 2)];
    System.out.println(byteBuffer[0].length);      // Giving wrong output

    int count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < byteBuffer.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < byteBuffer[0].length; i++) {
            final int x = (int) ((buffer[j][count++]) * Short.MAX_VALUE);
            byteBuffer[j][i++] = (byte) x;
            byteBuffer[j][i] = (byte) (x / 256);       //Total Value of Byte
        }
    }
    File out = new File("E:/RecordAudio7.wav"); //The path where user want the file data to be written

    //Construct an audio format, using 44100hz sampling rate, 16 bit samples, mono, and big 
    // endian byte ordering
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat((float) SAMPLING_RATE, 16, 1, true, false);

    // It uses bytebuffer as its buffer array that contains bytes that may be read from the stream.
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteBuffer[0]);

    //Constructs an audio input stream that has the requested format and length in sample frames, using audio data 
    //from the specified input stream.
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(bais, format, buffer.length);

    //Writes a stream of bytes representing an audio file of the specified file type to the external file provided.
    AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, out);

    audioInputStream.close();       //Closes this audio input stream
}
```

}

Comment: *"And if possible please.."* ..ask a question. Also please refrain from posting a 'shopping list' of requirements. SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk. See also [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay Sir. I'll keep all that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer for the first part of my question.
There was just a minor change in the code:

```
byte byteBuffer[][] = new byte[2][(int)(buffer[0].length * 2)];
```

instead of

```
 byte byteBuffer[][] = new byte[2][(int)(buffer.length * 2)];
```

Answer (score 1):

declaring `byteBuffer` is not correct
you are using `buffer.length` which is 2 that's why output is `4`

use `buffer[0].length * 2` instead of `buffer.length * 2` as below:

```
byte byteBuffer[][] = new byte[2][(int)(buffer[0].length * 2)];
```

for the second part, (passing 2D array into ByteArrayInputStream)
you can put the 2D elements into a 1D longer array
where it's length will equals `byteBuffer[0].length*byteBuffer.length`

you can use `System.arraycopy()` something like this:

```
int newArrayLength = byteBuffer.length*byteBuffer[0].length;
byte oneArray[] = new byte[newArrayLength];

//arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
for(int b=0;b<byteBuffer.length;b++){
    System.arraycopy(byteBuffer[b], 0, oneArray, (b*byteBuffer[b].length), byteBuffer[b].length)
}
```

what this code do is converting this

`byteBuffer` (2D)

0-[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]...

1-[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]...

2-[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]...

into this:

`oneArray` (1D)

```
[][][][][][][]...[][][][][][][]...[][][][][][][]...
```

And use `oneArray` for your `ByteArrayInputStream`

P.S: if your app will continue running after this step, it's good to release memory allocated for `byteBuffer` as it's not needed anymore, because you will work with `oneArray`, you can release memory by un-referencing it.

`byteBuffer=null;`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yazan, but my problem is not yet resolved. The .wav file that I am creating is actually producing no sound at all, but I think that is because I am taking a 2D array. As earlier I was working on the same code for just 1 frequency with 1D array and it was working just fine.
So now I am rethinking the whole logic again with 1D array for 2 frequencies, that I can add alternatively in the .wav file.
Any suggestions and help is really appreciated.

Comment: @VibhavChaddha i am not sure about wav files, but there are 2 types i think, mono and stereo maybe you have to use stereo?